# Golf randomly cuts out while driving, won't restart

Tags: electrical, vw, golf, no-crank-no-start

I have the following problem with my carburetted 2004 VW Golf 1.4 L.

While driving, it will just die or "cut out" for no reason. All the gauges jump on and off and everything is dead, and the car will not restart.

I can't seem to find the problem. Could anyone help me?

Comment: VW was still making carb models in 2004 really? Where in the world is this?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem before on an older Golf where there was a hairline crack in the fuse board and going over bumps or turning left caused the electrical power to disappear causing the car to temporarily stop.

My first suggestion would be to check all of the wiring to the battery terminals paying particular attention to the fused wiring that sits above the battery.